# How do I see with Android Studio from where the generated code in a BR file originates?

Tags: android, android-databinding

I'm entering a new codebase and have to understand how it works. There's a BR file that's autogenerated. I think it comes from the Data Binding Library. That BR files contains a lot of values, but I see no way to automatically search for the area in the code from where the content of that file gets specified.

When I have for example:

```
    public static final int currentDate = 35;
    public static final int currentEmail = 36;
```

How do I lookup where the code that results in those variables existing originates?

Comment: AndroidStudio's find usages should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I see no way to automatically search for the area in the code from
>   where the content of that file gets specified.

First of all, **BR** file is **auto generated** which will not let you know where from the fields generated. Same like you can not search **R** fields, where they belong to.

But there are normally two types of fields generated in **BR** file.

- 1st is `<variable` defined in your layout.

  ```
  <variable
      name="model"
      type="sample.data.Model"/>
  ```
- 2nd is `@Bindable` fields.

  ```
  @Bindable
  public String getPassword() {
      return password;
  }
  ```

So BR file look like

```
public class BR {
        public static final int _all = 0;
        public static final int model = 0;
        public static final int password = 1;
}
```

`_all` is some default integer which always gets generated.

Answer (score 0):

Usually **generated code** relies under this path:

*path to project/app/build/generated/rs*

> To check that in Android studio, you can change project structure view
>   from 'Android' to 'Project' and follow above path to see generated
>   code.

Answer (score 0):

That's a bit tricky to find. You can right click on a field and choose "Find Usages" but that will only show you where it's used, not where it originates from. The fields in BR.java are generated from methods marked with `@Bindable` Like

```
@Bindable
public String getSomeStringValue() {
    return "Some arbitrary string.";
}
```

Which will result in a field in the BR.java file looking like:

```
public static final int someStringValue = 126;
```

So to be able to find where something in the BR-file originates from you take what's in the BR.java file and slap on a "get" and then search for it. Myself, I would probably search for `@Bindable` instead.